# Branch in a private pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a private pod which has two branches master and develop.

My current project is using the that pod:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"

target "FooTarget" do

pod 'INCFoo'

end
```

So, currently I'm using master. I'd like to use the develop branch. I tried with:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"

target "FooTarget" do

pod 'INCFoo', :branch => 'develop'

end
```

But I get: [!] Unknown external source parameters for 'INCFoo' : {branch=>"develop"}

Finally it's working with:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"

target "FooTarget" do

pod 'INCFoo', :git => 'git@github.com/INCFoo.git' :branch => 'develop'

end
```

Is there any way to do it without adding the repository?

Thanks

Comment: What you may be able to do, is use subspec in the podspec, one for the develop, the other one for the master. And use `pod 'INCFoo-master'` or `pod 'INCFoo-develop`?

Comment: @xarly the pod line is incorrect, you should add a coma between the git ssh url and the :branch. Otherwise there is a syntax error